# DynamicFileListRecordReader waits indefinitely

Tags: hadoop, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google BigQuery Hadoop connector and experiencing an issue with it.
DynamicFileListRecordReader expects 0-record file to be present at the bucket path, but looks like it's not automatically created, so the reader goes into infinite loop.
According to this
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery 
this 0-record file is created only when using wildcard urls. But according to hadoop log single-url with no wildcards is used and that wait is unnecessary

My config for haddop job is

```
BigQueryConfiguration.configureBigQueryInput(conf, "publicdata:samples.shakespeare");
    conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem");
    // tempoary path where to download data from BiqQuery tables
    conf.set(BigQueryConfiguration.TEMP_GCS_PATH_KEY, "gs://mybucket/mypath");
    conf.set(BigQueryConfiguration.PROJECT_ID_KEY, "myprojid");
    conf.set(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.GCS_PROJECT_ID_KEY, "myprojid");
```

Comment: I see that an issue was raised on the project's GitHub page, which is the right course of action - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/issues/23.